# how to display the arc gis esri map on asp.net by using arcgis sdk

Tags: asp.net, sdk, arcgis

I want to display esri map on asp.net by using arcgis sdk.

Using an arcgis sdk enable me to do data handling on the map. The project is for meteorological department and want to display the map and weather parameters on the map by using asp.net.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [ArcGIS API for JavaScript](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/) in your ASP page.

If you have ArcGIS Server, there's something older called the [Web ADF for .NET](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/serveradf_net/adf_home.html), but the API for JavaScript is highly recommended for all new development.